# Aggregate + $project + $group + $sum + $count + $group again in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

Consider the Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EightWeekGamePlanSchema = new Schema({
  Week: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  LeadId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  SupplierGeneralId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },


  // ... More properties


  TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    // incresed by 1 every time it's claimed
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },



  InsertDate: {
    type: Date
    // default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = EightWeekGamePlan = mongoose.model(
  "eightweekgameplan",
  EightWeekGamePlanSchema
);
```

And consider the Mongo query :

```
   EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
      [
        // 1.Group by supplier
        // 2.Within each supplier group by month & year
        // Use count & sum
        {
          $project: {
            month: { $month: "$InsertDate" },
            year: { $year: "$InsertDate" }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              SupplierGeneralId: "$SupplierGeneralId",
              month: "$month",
              year: "$year"
            },
            ClaimsSummary : { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" } , 
            // TotalLeadsPerSupplierAndDate :  ... 

            // Here I want to group again , by LeadID and count all the 
            // unique LeadID's 
          }
        }       
       ]
```

1. I want to group by `SupplierGeneralId` and `Month + Year` of `InsertDate` ,
2. Summarize for each month the `TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType`
3. Group again but this time by the LeadID , and count all the unique LeadIds for each supplier  (previously grouped by SupplierGeneralId, Month, Year).

However I'm getting

> [ { _id: { month: 1, year: 2020 }, ClaimsSummary: 0 } ]

...even though there is data.

What's wrong with the pipeline ? and how can I group again to get the unique LeadIds for each supplier ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've added more fields to the `Project` but now I'm getting empty array in the `$push` :

```
   EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
      [
        // 1.Group by supplier
        // 2.Within each supplier group by month & year
        // Use count & sum
        { $sort: { SupplierGeneralId: 1 } },
        {
          $project: {
            month: { $month: "$InsertDate" },
            year: { $year: "$InsertDate" },
            SupplierGeneralId: "$SupplierGeneralId",
            TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType:
              "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              SupplierGeneralId: "$SupplierGeneralId",
              month: "$month",
              year: "$year"
            },
            LeadsCollection: {
              $push: {
                LeadId: "$LeadId"
              }
            },
            ClaimsSummary: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
          }
        }
        ]
```

Output:

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     _id: {
[0]       SupplierGeneralId: 'qCwHWFD1cBvrfPp5hdBL6M',
[0]       month: 1,
[0]       year: 2020
[0]     },
[0]     LeadsCollection: [
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
[0]       {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
[0]     ],
[0]     ClaimsSummary: 4
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

**SECOND EDIT :**

```
  EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
      [
        { $sort: { SupplierGeneralId: 1 } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              SupplierGeneralId: "$SupplierGeneralId",
              month: { $month: "$InsertDate" },
              year: { $year: "$InsertDate" }
            },
            LeadsUploaded: {
              $push: {
                LeadId: "$LeadId"
              }
            },
            Sells: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            Sells: "$Sells",
            LeadsUploaded: {
              $reduce: {
                input: { $setUnion: "$LeadsUploaded.LeadId" },
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    [
                      {
                        Lead_ID: "$$this"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Please share collection ?

Comment: Try using `$addFields` instead of `$project` in the aggregation's _first_ stage.

Comment: Use as @prasad_ said and also one more way to achieve that is project two more fields as SupplierGeneralId:1, TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType:1

Comment: @PrasathBV: I have , but now I'm getting empty array in the $push.

Comment: Also, add the `LeadId` to the project. You see, _project_ restricts the fields specified - its a projection of fields you want. So, you should specify _all_ the fields you want to use further down the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just drop the `$project` stage, you're grouping right after so theres no real point of doing it, adding it just makes the pipeline less efficient.

Rewrite your pipeline as:

```
EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
      [
        // 1.Group by supplier
        // 2.Within each supplier group by month & year
        // Use count & sum
        { $sort: { SupplierGeneralId: 1 } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              SupplierGeneralId: "$SupplierGeneralId",
              month: {"$month" : "$InsertDate"},
              year: { $year: "$InsertDate" },
            },
            LeadsCollection: {
              $push: {
                LeadId: "$LeadId"
              }
            },
            ClaimsSummary: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
          }
        }
        ]
```

Comment: Great answer , thanks, but how can we group again within the group , by LeadId ? I've edited my question based on your answer , and built another $project that returns an array of leads for every supplier , is it possible to only return its length ?

Comment: its possible but do you want to group by it or just count the amount of leadIds?